# Acidentally uninstalled Google app on Android phone

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, google, samsung-galaxy-s-5, google-play-services, google-assistant

I accidentally joined the beta program for the [Google search](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox) app on android, in ordered to leave the program I had to uninstall the app and re-install it. When I did this, everything seemed to be working fine. But now when I open my Google assistant by holding the home button, it opens the Google app instead of the google assistant. So I  went to my device settings and tried to change my assistant app, it was set to Google as it was before and as it should be. I remember though that my phone (A Samsung Galaxy S5) came with the Google assistant pre-installed, so I looked for it on Google Play and found it uninstalled, so I installed it. Upon opening it told my device wasn't compatible and I need to be running a Google app that was 6.0 or higher, well, after checking I found I'm running 9.66 so I should be fine.
I don't know how a simple re-install would have broken my Google assistant so bad. 
My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S5 running Android 6.0

I still haven't revised an answer to this question but I need it fixed, if I'm not clear enough or someone has a question PLEASE speak up.

Comment: According to me, uninstalling a pre-installed app in Android isn't possible without root. Is your device rooted?

Comment: @PuspamAdak No, my device is not rooted, maybe this is different for newer or older android versions though.